# Load extra data for MyBB from second database

Tags: php, mysql, mybb

I have created new page in MyBB for an aplication. Aplication needs to use database that is on a different host than the main MyBB database. I tried to use php pdo and mysqli to create a connection but in both cases I got an error: Access denied for user user@host....
Is MyBB somehow blocking other database connections or can I create another database connection with MyBB own functions?

Comment: what is needed is 1) what is your host, 2) where is mysql server, 3) who is the host of the server (i dont know what MyBB is), 4) what is the connection info for hostname and username (password not needed) 5) can you run a query as root on mysql server

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you export the database of your MySQL and import it into the database where MyBB is stored?